# How to serilize too big of an object and not running out of memory

Tags: php, memory, error-handling, sizeof, php-7.1

In my error handling process, I am dumping a `$obj_to_log = print_r($obj,true)` output to my error logs (file/db/redis).
Sometimes $obj is too big, and it will crash at this point (as this essentially duplicate the memory footprint held by the object).
Is there a way I can dump such big objects to file (beside continually increasing memory).
The object currently causing me issues is a Third party library, I can't modify/optimize the object itself.

While right now the problem is caused by only one object, I need my error handling to be robust and be able to handle any object, not all of them (objects in the world) have a __tostring or other error reporting mechanizes.

The reason I serialize the object into a variable is implementation reason, I gather the info in one place, and write to the relevant log type in another place. I guess I can solve this by passing the function that generates the info into the relevant logger class, instead of just the data.

Comment: Surely you don't have to log the entire object? Does it not contain an error or whatever kind of property?

Comment: which 3rd party lib? which class?

Comment: usually those objects come with builtin introspection features. There should be a special method equivalent to print_r without the clutter.

Comment: why do you have to make a separate $obj_to_log variable? Can't you send the output of `print_r($obj,true)`) directly to the file (or to the logger function)? I would guess that wouldn't cause the memory to be increased as much.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Google lib to talk to their Spreadsheets.

Comment: @ADyson see my edits, u did gave me an idea there +1